# How make a Level Unlocker using GUI Buttons and PlayerPrefs things?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
#pragma strict

var challenge1 : Texture;
var challenge2 : Texture;
var challenge3 : Texture;
var LevelOneEnabled = true;
var LevelTwoEnabled = false;
var LevelThreeEnabled = false;
var Score : TextMesh;
var Score2 : TextMesh;
var Score3 : TextMesh;
function Start(){

}
function Awake(){
Score.text = "Highscore: "+ PlayerPrefs.GetInt("JeepneyScore");
Score2.text = "Highscore: "+ PlayerPrefs.GetInt("JeepneyScore2");
Score3.text = "Best Time: "+ PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("JeepneyScore3");
}
function OnGUI()
{


GUI.enabled = LevelOneEnabled;
if(GUI.Button(Rect(400,100,250,250),challenge1)){
Application.LoadLevel("LoadScene");
}
GUI.enabled = LevelTwoEnabled;
if(GUI.Button(Rect(700,100,250,250),challenge2)){
Application.LoadLevel("LoadScene2");
}
GUI.enabled = LevelThreeEnabled;
if(GUI.Button(Rect(1000,100,250,250),challenge3)){
Application.LoadLevel("LoadScene3");
}

}
```

- Can anybody knows hot to get the logic in playerprefs so that the LoadScene2, and 3 
  will unlock after finishing the first mission?
  Please I'm hoping for an answer :(

Answer (score 0):

put in

```
var level : int;
```

then in start

```
level = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level",0);
```

then in your if(GUI.Buttons){}

```
if(level >= 2){}
```

and

```
if(level >= 3){}
```

and so on and in your actual levels set the int in your playerprefs once they complete the level, probably load the int again and use if to check if it is greater than then replace if it is not

EDIT:

```
var levelnum : int = 2;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level",levelnum);
```

Comment: what will I add in my script ?     var score = 0;
    var mySkin : GUISkin;
    var GUIScore : GUIText;
    
    function Start(){
    GUIScore.text = "Score: 0";
    }
     
    function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider ) {
    if (other.tag == "ParkSuccess") {
     SaveScore();
    }
    
     Application.LoadLevel("Levels");
    }

Comment: i guess use a boolean to triger when the level is completed and then set the int

Comment: if you didnt set the int yet and you use level = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level",0); it is going to default to '0'

Comment: var levelnum : int =2; function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider ) {
    if (other.tag == "ParkSuccess") {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LoadScene2",levelnum); is this the right code?

Comment: when you getInt you have to use LoadScene2 with that, its up to you, i dont know exactly what you are doing

Comment: where will i use the Set int function?

Comment: in your levels, your scenes when the level is complete so they can unlock the next level right?

Comment: var score = 0;
    var mySkin : GUISkin;
    var GUIScore : GUIText;
    var levelnum : int = 2;
    
    function Start(){
    GUIScore.text = "Score: 0";
    }
     
    function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider ) {
    if (other.tag == "ParkSuccess") {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LoadScene2",levelnum);
     SaveScore();
    }

Comment: I want to unlock LoadScene2

Comment: I have this collider parksuccess when i trigger on it, it will go to the levels scene and that is the script in level scene